# How do I set a site collection's list view to be inherited?

Tags: list-view

I have a added a column to my the "Documents" default list view at the site collection level for my Publishing site. How do I get this view to be available to all of the sub sites?

Is this an unusual thing to do? Doesn't is make sense that default lists are uniform? I am adding a metadata column to my Documents list - why wouldn't I want that column to be available throughout the Site Collection?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the column in all documents in the site collection then you'd added it to the Document Content Type instead to a specific list

Comment: Should I create a new content type or edit the default?

Comment: Edit the default if you want it to automatically apply to all document libraries

Answer (score 0):

If you want the view of that list to appear on all sub-sites, you can make the list as global... Following article shows how you can make a list global by using SharePoint Designer

http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/creating-global-list-or-library-web-parts-with-sharepoint-designer-2010/

But keep in mind, what it just do will add a webpart in Custom category for the list you made GLOBAL and you can use that webpart/view in sub-sites...

I hope this answers your question!